# Objective-c input conversion stopped due to an input byte that does not belong to the input codeset UTF-8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send a hex command to a bluetooth printer.  One of the characters determines the size of the data I can pass.  The string is:

> @"\x1d\x28\x6b\xff\x00\x31\x50\x30\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x20\x66\x61\x72\x74\x20\x70\x6f\x6f\x70\x79\x2e\x2e\x2e\x2e"

I get the error in the title when I do this.  The reason is I am passing ff (first line - 16 characters in), which is outside the codeset for UTF-8.  If I set this to 7f, which is in the codeset, everything works fine.

I have tried several different things but I am unable to fix this issue.

Comment: Why not create an `NSData` object instead of an `NSString`? It will be better to package the bytes as data.

Comment: so is the problem that you want to send a non-UTF-8 char to an interface that only accepts UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to something like the following:

```
uint8_t bytes[] = { 0x1d, 0x28, 0x6b, 0xff, 0x00, 0x31, 0x50, 0x30, 0x66, ... };
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
```

Now you can use the `NSData` to send the hex command.